# Why can't I pass a pointer to fmt.Println using flag.StringVar?

Tags: go

I've started looking at Golang, and following an example to pass in command line arguments, I've got this code:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    wordPtr := flag.String("namestring", "stringvalue", "Pass in a string")
    numPtr := flag.Int("number", 11, "Pass in an int")
    boolPtr := flag.Bool("switchflag", false, "Pass in a bool")
    var svar string
    flag.StringVar(&svar, "svar", "svarstringvalue", "A string variable")
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Println("Word:", *wordPtr)
    fmt.Println("Word2:", wordPtr)
    fmt.Println("numb:", *numPtr)
    fmt.Println("numb2", numPtr)
    fmt.Println("switchflag", *boolPtr)
    fmt.Println("switchflag2", boolPtr)
    fmt.Println("svar:", svar)
    fmt.Println("svar2", &svar)
    fmt.Println("svar3", *svar) //<-- This won't work...
    fmt.Println("tail:", flag.Args())

}
```

My question is, why do I get the value of the other pointers if I dereference it (like `*wordPtr` etc), whereas if I pass `wordPtr` in, I get the memory address, but with `svar`, I have to pass in `svar` to get the value, and `&svar` gets me the memory address?

Looking at the documentation here https://golang.org/pkg/flag/, it says that you pass in a variable to store the flag (presumably a variable that is already created?), but I still don't understand why I have to do something different to it to get the value, when compared with other variables.

This is the result of me running it with passing in some commands:

```
➜  Documents go run main.go -number 42 -switchflag -svar testtringvalue
Word: stringvalue
Word2: 0xc42005c1e0
numb: 42
numb2 0xc4200160a0
switchflag true
switchflag2 0xc4200160a8
svar: testtringvalue
svar2 0xc42005c1f0
tail: []
```

Any help is appreciated. Also, if I've got any understanding of it wrong, please let me know.

Cheers.

Comment: svar is of type `string`, so it can't be dereferenced. `wordPtr` is of type `*string`, so it can be dereferenced. I'm not really sure why this is confusing.

Comment: This has nothing to do with package flag but is the normal behavior of pointers in Go. Take the Tour of Go which explains this much better than any answer on SO.

Comment: When I look up types in Golang, I only see `string`, not `*string`. What is a `*string` called?

It's confusing because I don't know C, and this is a new language for me (previously used Python and PowerShell).

On this page of the documentation https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/, I also can't see a type called `*string`.

Comment: @Volker I wasn't suggesting it was an issue with the flag package, but rather that that's where I was trying to use it.

Comment: `*string` is called "pointer to string": https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is fairly simple, you are trying to dereference a value instead of pointer.

`var svar string` is not a pointer, but a value.

`fmt.Println("svar3", svar)` is correct use in this case

Don't worry about about use of StringVar as 
`...Var(&svar, "sv...` means that you are passing address of `svar` not a value.

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer I was looking for.